# How to add property to a global Javascript object inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tying to add a property to a JS object inside a function. I can do it outside but not inside. Please explain. Sorry. I am missing something very basic here.

```
var newobj = {'prop1' : 12, 'prop2' : 25};

myfunc(newobj);

function myfunc(someobj) {
   someobj.prop3 = 45;
}
```

This gives a syntax error.

Comment: This works for me. If I run this script, `newobj` has its `prop3` set to `45`. There's no errors.

Comment: There's probably a difference between your actual code and the way you've summarized it here. We can't tell you where your syntax error is if you don't show the original code.

Comment: Please show full code, because there's obviously nothing wrong with this sample ;)

Comment: As Joeytje50 said, the code you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6fDX5/

Comment: Sorry! Gentlemen!! You are right, the problem was somewhere else. Fixed it. REAL APOLOGIES. While simplifying the problem to present here, I found the solution... Thanks again. Will upvote all correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are something else is interfering because [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/Bcp99/) for me.

If you dump `newobj` before the function call you get:

```
{"prop1":12,"prop2":25}
```

And after the function call:

```
{"prop1":12,"prop2":25,"prop3":45}
```

As you can see, the new property has been added.

I would suggest either looking at what you have more closesly (make sure you're not copying the value and then passing it) or add some `console.log` call in your code as it goes through. You can also, in most of the browsers, use the debugger to step through the code to see where it may be fouled.

Comment: So your answer is that it works and the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: @j08691: Short of a better question, yes. Also, further information on how the user can research where the problem may be getting introduced.

Comment: As I said... my apologies. Deserve the downvote! Will accept this answer. It is a correct answer afterall.